# Warning: Load biblatex with (biblatex) the "backend=bibtex" option

Tags: biblatex, biber

i am trying to compile a work in Texmaker, but when doing so, the console returns:

```
Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
(biblatex) To use BibTeX, load biblatex with
(biblatex) the "backend=bibtex" option.
```

I really do not know what does it means.

My preamble is the next:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtex.bib}
```

Comment: As you can see from the log it is a warning, not an error.  If you are fine with using `biber`, just leave everything as is and ignore the warning (or explicitly use `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`).  If for some reason you need `bibtex`, then use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` (not recommended).

Comment: You can read up on the differences between Biber and BibTeX in [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701). Nowadays you will want to use the Biber backend; BibTeX is only supported as legacy backend and does not support the full set of features. If your document compiles fine otherwise, you can simply write `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` to suppress the warning and make explicit that you use Biber. In case you have problems with Biber see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751).

Comment: @moewe Yes, it was solved. Thank both of you